# Re-installing ubuntu to format my dual-boot system configuration?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I decided to try out the new windows 8 (then 8.1) when buying a new computer to be able to run microsoft software cleanly. I still installed ubuntu as a dual-boot system (splitting my drive's space 50/50). Now I want to re-install ubuntu and to get completely rid of windows (and never look back). Now, that isn't much of a problem. My question is simple:

If I decide to install ubuntu once again, and extending the installation to the entire hard drive (if that is still possible), would my partitions (that have been divided previously for the dual-boot) "fuse" back together? Meaning firstly that I'd get all of my hard drive space back on ubuntu.

Technically, I'd say yes. But most of the questions ask how to delete one OS while keeping the other boot. I want to know if I can do that while taking a simpler, more direct way or if I have to go through deleting the OS before reinstalling ubuntu anyway. I haven't even looked at what I can do with my grub repair for that matter, and I am pretty sure it can do what I want through another way. Yet, I find that format-installing ubuntu is the 1) simplest, 2) easiest, but also 3) the most complete/reassuring way to erase my dual-boot system.

I'm clearly not an ubuntu guru.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want just Ubuntu on your hard disk and nothing else, you can do that during installation or you could just delete the Windows installation.

To erase the entire disk and install Ubuntu, just select `Erase and use entire disk` when you boot from your Ubuntu CD / USB stick.

A standard installation guide is given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation).